# Does Kue subscribe to any (*) pattern with Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, kue

I am experimenting with Redis and needed queues to receive realtime notifications in nodejs from Redis and publish to connected clients. I used Kue for this purpose. 
Reading Redis documentation, you subscribe with a channel pattern that you are interested in, Wanted to know how does Kue achieve this. Need some pointers to documentation or code where I can understand this.

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered similar in the past and have dug around for answers. I presume you mean wildcard job processing, for instance..

```
queue.process('file:*', function(job, done){
    // process any 'file:' job type e.g. 'file:move' 'file:copy' 
})
```

And it appears that is doesn't. See [Wildcard support for job processing](https://github.com/Automattic/kue/issues/586)

A way round it however is to use the job type as the `file` part, and then set a task name in the job data that you can then attempt to process yourself. For instance...

```
queue.process('file', function(err, done){
    var taskType = job.data.taskType;

    switch (taskType){
        case 'move':
            // do move job
            break;
        case 'copy':
            // do copy job
            break;
        default:
            // do something else
    }
});
```